# IIS7 GZIP Compression - httpCompression section

Tags: iis-7, web-config, gzip

I trying to configure `httpCompression` on IIS7. By googling, I found that it can be made using `httpCompression` section in config.  The problem, that I can't make it work from web.config.

When I make the configuration in `applicationHost.config` everything works as needed, but I want to be able to make this configuration per application and not globally.

I changed section definition in `applicationHost.config` to `<section name="httpCompression" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />` and moved `httpCompression` section to web.config:

```
<httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files">
      <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" />
      <staticTypes>
        <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/atom+xml" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/xaml+xml" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
      </staticTypes>
      <dynamicTypes>
        <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/json; charset=utf-8" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
      </dynamicTypes>
    </httpCompression>
```

What am I missing? It looks like IIS not reads compression configurations from web.config at all.

After each change, I make application pool recycle, so it not a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check the whole [config file hierarchy](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/01/17/10-things-asp-net-developers-should-know-about-web-config-inheritance-and-overrides.aspx).

If you removed the section from `applicationHost` you may be inheriting from `machine.config` or a `web.config` of a parent directory.

Comment: I found the solution. I modified section definition in applicationHost.config from <section name="httpCompression" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />, to <section name="httpCompression" allowDefinition="Everywhere" overrideModeDefault="Allow" /> (allowDefinition="Everywhere" solved the problem). Thank you

Comment: @AlexDn: I guess you should post your solution as an actual answer.

Comment: @sharptooth actually I was able to configure it only on IIS Server level. Didn't found the solution for per application configuration.

Comment: @AlexDn: Whatever, your solution with its limitations description will be more usable when posted as an answer.

Answer (score 6):

as per this ServerFault answer: https://serverfault.com/a/125156/117212 - you can't change httpCompression in web.config, it needs to be done in applicationHost.config file. Here is the code I use in my Azure web role to modify applicationHost.config file and add mime types for compression:

```
using (var serverManager = new ServerManager())
{
    var config = serverManager.GetApplicationHostConfiguration();
    var httpCompressionSection = config.GetSection("system.webServer/httpCompression");
    var dynamicTypesCollection = httpCompressionSection.GetCollection("dynamicTypes");

    Action<string> fnCheckAndAddIfMissing = mimeType =>
    {
        if (dynamicTypesCollection.Any(x =>
        {
            var v = x.GetAttributeValue("mimeType");
            if (v != null && v.ToString() == mimeType)
            {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }) == false)
        {
            ConfigurationElement addElement = dynamicTypesCollection.CreateElement("add");
            addElement["mimeType"] = mimeType;
            addElement["enabled"] = true;
            dynamicTypesCollection.AddAt(0, addElement);
        }
    };

    fnCheckAndAddIfMissing("application/json");
    fnCheckAndAddIfMissing("application/json; charset=utf-8");

    serverManager.CommitChanges();
}
```

`ServerManager` comes from `Microsoft.Web.Administration` package in NuGet.